# MonoGame - NoSuitableGraphicsDeviceException

Tags: c#, monogame, mono

I'm trying to create a cross-platform MonoGame project on Linux. However, the application fails to run - it throws a NoSuitableGraphicsDeviceException. I have no clue as to what causes this. Does it have something to do with graphics drivers?

Here's the stack trace:

```
Unhandled Exception:
    Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.NoSuitableGraphicsDeviceException: Failed to create graphics device! ---> System.EntryPointNotFoundException: SDL_SetWindowResizable
      at (wrapper managed-to-native) Sdl+Window:SetResizable (intptr,bool)
      at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.SdlGameWindow.CreateWindow () [0x00098] in <c31673e23fbb4b338ace0c0a31a4b94e>:0 
      at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GraphicsDeviceManager.PlatformInitialize (Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.PresentationParameters presentationParameters) [0x000d8] in <c31673e23fbb4b338ace0c0a31a4b94e>:0 
      at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GraphicsDeviceManager.Initialize () [0x00023] in <c31673e23fbb4b338ace0c0a31a4b94e>:0 
      at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GraphicsDeviceManager.CreateDevice () [0x00011] in <c31673e23fbb4b338ace0c0a31a4b94e>:0 
       --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
      at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GraphicsDeviceManager.CreateDevice () [0x00036] in <c31673e23fbb4b338ace0c0a31a4b94e>:0 
      at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GraphicsDeviceManager.Microsoft.Xna.Framework.IGraphicsDeviceManager.CreateDevice () [0x00000] in <c31673e23fbb4b338ace0c0a31a4b94e>:0 
      at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game.DoInitialize () [0x00016] in <c31673e23fbb4b338ace0c0a31a4b94e>:0 
      at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game.Run (Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GameRunBehavior runBehavior) [0x0002d] in <c31673e23fbb4b338ace0c0a31a4b94e>:0 
      at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game.Run () [0x0000c] in <c31673e23fbb4b338ace0c0a31a4b94e>:0 
      at MaijaSokoban.Program.Main () [0x00007] in <ffbdf0478cf84377b5ca9b241123624d>:0 
    [ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.NoSuitableGraphicsDeviceException: Failed to create graphics device! ---> System.EntryPointNotFoundException: SDL_SetWindowResizable
      at (wrapper managed-to-native) Sdl+Window:SetResizable (intptr,bool)
      at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.SdlGameWindow.CreateWindow () [0x00098] in <c31673e23fbb4b338ace0c0a31a4b94e>:0 
      at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GraphicsDeviceManager.PlatformInitialize (Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.PresentationParameters presentationParameters) [0x000d8] in <c31673e23fbb4b338ace0c0a31a4b94e>:0 
      at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GraphicsDeviceManager.Initialize () [0x00023] in <c31673e23fbb4b338ace0c0a31a4b94e>:0 
      at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GraphicsDeviceManager.CreateDevice () [0x00011] in <c31673e23fbb4b338ace0c0a31a4b94e>:0 
       --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
      at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GraphicsDeviceManager.CreateDevice () [0x00036] in <c31673e23fbb4b338ace0c0a31a4b94e>:0 
      at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GraphicsDeviceManager.Microsoft.Xna.Framework.IGraphicsDeviceManager.CreateDevice () [0x00000] in <c31673e23fbb4b338ace0c0a31a4b94e>:0 
      at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game.DoInitialize () [0x00016] in <c31673e23fbb4b338ace0c0a31a4b94e>:0 
      at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game.Run (Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GameRunBehavior runBehavior) [0x0002d] in <c31673e23fbb4b338ace0c0a31a4b94e>:0 
      at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game.Run () [0x0000c] in <c31673e23fbb4b338ace0c0a31a4b94e>:0 
      at MaijaSokoban.Program.Main () [0x00007] in <ffbdf0478cf84377b5ca9b241123624d>:0
```

Here's all of my code:

```
// Program.cs

using System;

namespace MaijaSokoban
{
    public static class Program
    {
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        using(var game = new MaijaSokoban())
            game.Run();
    }
    }
}

// MaijaSokoban.cs

using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;

namespace MaijaSokoban
{
    public class MaijaSokoban : Game
    {
    private GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
    private SpriteBatch spriteBatch;

    public MaijaSokoban()
    {
        graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
        Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
    }

    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        base.Initialize();
    }

    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
    }

    protected override void UnloadContent()
    {

    }

    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        base.Update(gameTime);
    }

    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, it is most likely related to either your GPU or the driver - the exception should be thrown if *"The graphics adapter does not support the requested capabilities."* (see [XNA docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff433790.aspx))